# Python3 in SublimeText3 configuration OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I have some programming experience in C++ but am trying to learn Python - I am struggling to get a "hello world" to display in Python3 via SublimeText 3 that I tried to configure today.  Been reading through the many posts on this topic and have not yet solved my problem, appreciate any insight.

So far I have:

Installed Python3 and SublimeText3 today using .dmg utility

Confirmed Python3 is installed via terminal, and paths are "/usr/local/bin/python3" and "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3"

Created new Python3.sublime-build file and saved to local "Users" directory with the following command:

```
{
  "cmd": ["usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
}
```

I then changed the Sublime Text Build System to Python3 in the "Tools" menu.

Created and saved a new .py file.  It built and ran successfully (Cmd + B) when prompted to `print("Hello")` but not when setting it to a variable

```
message = "Hello"
print(message)
```

It returns a syntax error:

```
  File "/Users/username/python_files/hello.py", line 2
message = "Hello"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3', '-u', '/Users/username/python_files/hello.py']]
[dir: /Users/username/python_work]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I saved the .py file before trying to build.  I tried other variations for the sublime-build command based on user suggestions, but none have worked:

```
"cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
```

Not really adept with Unix or OSX terminal so my own troubleshooting is a bit limited. Where should I be looking next to get this thing to work?  Grateful for help, and eager to get started.

Comment: I am using both ST3 and VSC (and some IDEs) but VSC wins it for me, I write commits in ST3 and thats about it. Maybe give it a try, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the helpful links - I sorted this out by realizing that my entire python3 code was contained within {} brackets - apparently this is incorrect.  To my credit, this formatting still ran with just the basic `print("Text")` within the brackets.  Wish me luck with my journey of discovery, sounds like I'll need it...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try already to follow this [instruction](https://gist.github.com/zaemiel/4fbd8b5125fda7a140be) step-by-step? I just tried it and the instruction works.

From your code listing it seems, that you specify

```
{
  "cmd": ["usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
}
```

while the Built-System Output says

```
[cmd: ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3', ...
```

There is a mix up of your python paths either on your system or in your listings. In the first case try to run python3 in your terminal and do

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

This will give you your correct python path. Copy the path and paste it in the `"cmd"` statement of your `.sublime-build` file

```
"cmd": ["/path/to/your/python/python3", "-u", "$file"]
```

This should do it

Comment: Thanks for link and update - I had seen and followed that instruction link but the syntax error persists.  I opened python3 in terminal, and confirmed the executable is the `/Library/Frameworks/` path.  I then changed the `cmd:` path to your suggested fix but it still gives a similar syntax error.  I initially installed python3 via .dmg, then later attempted the Homebrew suggestion as part of troubleshooting, not sure if that accounts for multiple paths.

Comment: hmm, ok. There is maybe an issue with OSX selecting automatically python2 (even if I see, that you configured the builder correctly to use your newer python3.7). Though, your "hello world" code should also work in python2. Anyway you can try to check if these [link](https://github.com/dreadatour/Flake8Lint/issues/69) here is useful